# Защита авторизационного токена Vue + Php

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cookie, авторизация

Клиент настаивает на хранении сессии сроком - полгода. Потребность выполнили. При авторизации пользователя, в БД генерируем уникальный (UUID) токен и отдаём на фронт со сроком хранения в полгода с последующим сохранением в куки, для использования на стороне Vue и на стороне php (админ панель на Laravel). Но возник вопрос. Безопасно ли хранение такого токена в куках? Данный вопрос возник, т.к. для связи единой авторизации между Vue и laravel админки - используется токен в куки параметрах. Если админ зашел на сайте, то в админку он уже попадет без повторного ввода пароля, т.к. в куки уже хранится его токен и по нему я узнаю, какой юзер и создаю сессию.

Какие еще есть варианты более безопасного хранения? Смотрел в сторону рефреш токен - по факту, то же самое, только токен обновляется часто. А толку? Так же хранится в куки, так же не безопасно. Или подмена и кража куков удаленно уже не актуальна? По факту, если ты имеешь доступ к ПК, то зачем воровать куки, если можно просто воспользоваться авторизацией на сайте и сделать свои грязные дела.

Буду рад услышать Ваши советы! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Передавать Cookie с параметрами [SameSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) Lax/None + Secure

Хранить отдельно Cookie фронта и бэка - параметр(ы) Domain и/или Path.